valid question singularly closed too soon
Having already done some research seeking similar problems, to no avail, I posted a question which feel is actually quite valid and could be broadly applicable to others.  Others may disagree, but there should at least be a chance to discuss or improve.
Open to suggestions to a better forum for it, but feel at least 1. it should have been allowed to air for longer than an hour esp. coming from a timezone where working hours fall on much of the English-speaking continent's sleeping, and 2. a mod should flag for discussion in favor of single-handedly closing.   Granted, I had promptly removed the background to be more terse and avoid mentioning specific vendors, if that was the issue.

When I closed your question, I stated that there isn't a professional quant in the world who would have started a question the way you did. Here's what you originally said:

Background: I'm stuck with a deadbeat life insurance policy holder
  (Western Reserve Life) who refuses to give customers historical
  pricing data of their fund selections under the pretext of "market
  timing". Their most recent performance metrics are uselessly out of
  date, typically from last quarter: "Average Returns as of 2011-12-31",
  basically on par with prospectuses(sp?), not previous market day's or
  week's closing as one would minimally hope. Their list of fund choices
  available for allocation are no where to be found by similar names at
  3rd party ratings like MorningStar, nor exhaustive Google searching.
  For example, find me OHLCV charts and reviews on TA BlackRock Tactical
  Allocation @$10.331/share, TA JPMorgan Tactical Allocation, TA
  BlackRock Global Allocation @9.970. TA=Transamerica presumably(the
  website is pretty bad).

I've also pointed you to the FAQ, which clearly states that this site is intended for professionals or academics in quantitative finance. What you posted above does not meet this criteria.
As for your suggestions:

There is no timeline for a question to "air". Any post that is clearly off-topic is closed immediately.
A moderator does not flag for discussion. A moderator exercises his powers according to his judgement.

This the case for every Stack Exchange site I've ever participated on. Had you posted on Stack Overflow about some software vendor who annoyed you that question would have been closed too.

Fair enough. Venting isn't appropriate even if it does warn others. Was going to close this pending discussion. Thanks for maintaining quality.
